# Where does ASP.Net Core `cookies authentication` store a reference to that cookie?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, cookies, asp.net-core

Sometimes I used to see PHP developers passing an Id in their cookies, and save a reference in the database to that cookie (so they can authenticate the users by cookies). But in ASP.Net Core, I have never seen that.

How and where does ASP.Net Core know that this cookie is owned by this user? Is everything stored in memory (in some kind of objects)?

In case of yes, does that mean that the users should be logged in again if I restarted my application? Or is there any method that ASP.Net Core provides to persist the references to cookies even after restarting the application?

Comment: The cookie is stored in the Browser. If the session is not expired, you should can reuse it.

Comment: @Nikolaus, yes, but when that cookie is sent back to server in the next request, how can the server know that this cookie is valid? what if the user is deactivated now? or changed password. How can the server revoke that cookie if is saved on the client and no reference is pointing to it in server side?

Comment: Cookie contains information about user in encrypted form, so it's different from type of cookie you describe (which stores only pointer to information about user).

Comment: @Evk, in this case what about restarting the app, and validation? will they be lost if I restarted the app (server side). And if nothing on the server is stored, how can I revoke these cookies (e.g. in case I want to deactivate a user)?

Comment: Restarting app should not affect cookies, because nothing is stored in memory about them. And until cookie expires - it will be valid even if you disable user.  You can intercept cookie validation and change that - read about one approach here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore2x#reacting-to-back-end-changes

Comment: This approach has both benefits and drawbacks. Benefit - no need to store anything, no need to bother database for each call to validate cookie info. Drawbacks - cookie size is bigger, some cpu is consumed to encrypt/decrypt it, harder to revoke.

Comment: @Evk,thank you. In this case they are not different from the cookies with a reference in the database, cuz I have anyway to access the database to compare with the current cookie.

Comment: It does have the option of storing the data locally and only sending an identifier, but that's not the default. See the ITicketStore: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/5e51cb5c691eda23e965a57ac5d83c8497ff40d6/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationOptions.cs#L135

Comment: @Tratcher, good to know, could you explain more about it in an answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The ClaimsPrincipal is serialiazed, encrypted and sent to the client as a cookie.  Once a cookie is created, it becomes the single source of identity.  When the client makes a request it sends the cookie, which the server decrypts (which serves as validation) and deserializes into the HttpContext.

Comment: Any idea what that cookie is named?

Comment: It's configurable but the default value is .AspNetCore.Cookies https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: @hobwell in ASP.NET Core 2.1 this cookie is named `.AspNetCore.Identity.Application`

Comment: But where and how is the cookie (or serialized ClaimsPrincipal) stored on the server?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that the server needs to store is the decryption key, which it stores as a [Data Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1) key. As per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/default-settings?view=aspnetcore-3.1), keys are persisted to these locations:

> If the app is hosted in Azure Apps, keys are persisted to the
> %HOME%\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys folder. This folder is backed by
> network storage and is synchronized across all machines hosting the
> app.

> If the user profile is available, keys are persisted to the
> %LOCALAPPDATA%\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys folder. If the operating
> system is Windows, the keys are encrypted at rest using DPAPI.